# I am trying to make a simple dataframe and the code I am using is not giving me what I expected

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I have the following function:

```
 linearPerf_DF = (linearPerf_Func(data));
```

This function returns two numbers, and typeof(linearPerf_DF) tells me it's a "double".  Not sure if this is the problem to begin with.  Looks like this in R when I print linearPerf_DF:

```
## [1] 0.2600 0.2601
## [1] "double"
```

In this case I can reference both variables like:

```
linearPerf_DF[1]
linearPerf_DF[2]
```

I have then built a simple dataframe with the initial intention of just rbind()'ing each line in this blank frame:

```
error_Df = data.frame(Error_Value = double(),Model_Type=character(),Test_or_train=character())
```

I am presenting the dataframe with a list where it allows me to loop through models more than once (since vector cannot hold different data structures):

```
error_Df[1+i,] = list(linearPerf_DF[1], "Linear", "Train")
error_Df[2+i,] = list(linearPerf_DF[2], "Linear", "Test")
error_Df[3+i,] = list(QuadPerf_DF[1], "Quadratic", "Train")
error_Df[4+i,] = list(QuadPerf_DF[2], "Quadratic", "Test")
```

What I want to see is

```
##   Error_Value  Model_Type Test_or_train
## 1      0.2600      Linear         Train
## 2      0.2601      Linear         Test
## 3      0.215      Quadratic      Train
## 4      0.2459      Quadratic      Test
```

but what I am really seeing is this:

```
##   Error_Value  Model_Type Test_or_train
## 1      0.2600      Linear         Train
## 2      0.2300      Linear         Train
## 3      0.3150      Linear         Train
## 4      0.2777      Linear          Test
```

The numbers are different because there are several more models, but I think my intention makes sense?  Basically I will cycle through each number in the model and then add those two columns for doing a boxplot. Spent hours on this and don't know what is wrong.

I cannot use anything but Base R so dyplr and other tools like that will not help.

Thanks very much.

EDIT:

print(dput(linearPerf_DF)) gives:

```
## c(0.26, 0.2601)
## [1] 0.2600 0.2601
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(linearPerf_DF)` to your post?

Comment: Maybe not solving that question, but you can create the same result with a one-liner: `data.frame(Error_Value=c(linearPerf_DF[1:2], QuadPerf_DF[1:2]), Model_Type=rep(c("Linear","Quadratic"), each=2), Test_or_train=rep(c("Train","Test"), times=2))`.

Comment: print(dput(linearPerf_DF)) gives: Please see above

Comment: Don't see anything wrong in the code with information that you have shared. Maybe you need to add some more details. I think you are running this in a `for` loop, maybe add how you are calling this in the loop. Can you create a small example where we can reproduce the error that you are facing?

Comment: When running `error_Df[1+i,] = `, `error_Df[2+i,] = `, ... in a loop, at the first iteration you write the rows 1, 2, 3, 4; at the second iteration you write the rows 2, 3, 4, 5 thus rewriting on top of the existing ones etc. What you would need to do for a correct `for` loop is to use `error_Df[1 + 4*(i-1), ] = ...` then `error_Df[2 + 4*(i-1),]=...` etc. But as pointed by r2evans, R has better ways to do that kind of looping, that avoid thinking about the individual indexes.

Comment: @Alexlok Oh wow you are right.  It should be 1+(8*i), 2+(8*i), etc.  Can't believe I didn't see this.  Thanks for taking the time to take a look at this.  I'll look into those other looping methods per your suggestion.